# "Access is denied." to Administrator

Tags: windows, administrator

i have enabled (and am currently logged in as) the built-in administrator account in windows 8.1 enterprise.
after executing the following command to change its password

```
net user administrator 123456
```

i get this error:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

ps:

it's not the only command i get this kind of error from, also for sharing (`net share`), and moving files from/to `System32` directory (`move`)

pps:

`Administrator` user is a member of the `Administrators` local group

Comment: Try running command prompt as an Administrator.

Comment: strangely enough, it worked. but the main reason i've activated the built-in administrator account is to avoid "running things as administrator" and other confirmation prompts. it's the first time i saw that kind of permission issue, because on my other computers i don't need to run executables as administrator when i AM Administrator (i mean i'm logged in as Administrator user)

Comment: I know. Never had trouble with Windows 7. Something has been changed in Windows 8 and in 8.1.

Comment: You still have to escalate the process even as the built-in Administrator.  This behavior is suppose to happen.